# Using BackupManager on a Android PHP-MySQL Server

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service

I'm making an Android application that uses a coin in-game currency (that can be bought using in apps billing) and with that virtual currency the user can buy items that can only be bought once.

To manage every purchase and how much coins each user has, I initially though of using a table for every purchase and user used in the application on the server where I keep my item list, but since my server is a low cost one and i think / hope there will be a lot of transactions, the server will not be able to deal with every user request in time (answering update lists, managing purchases, sending the items to user and so forth).

Recently I found out about [BackupManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) and I was thinking if I used a local file to save the user coins, the updated list of items and the purchases the user has done instead of using the server, and then when one of these changes (when purchasing a new item, when updating the list of items, etc) i would update the local file and the backup using `BackupManager` without even contacting my server. Is that doable, is the `BackupManager` designed to work with very frequent backups like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong approach as you are open to "frauds". On rooted devices people could easily replace or modify your "wallet" file and without own records you will not be able to catch that.

And BackupManager is well... for backups, so I am not really see a correlation between your needs and backups.